# Two XML trees, are they the same?

Tags: xml

I need to know if these two declarations are the same or not?

```
<products>
  <product>
    <item></item>
  </product>
  <product>
    <item></item>
  </product>
</products>
```

and

```
<products>
  <product>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
  </product>
</products>
```

rg,
Eric

Comment: Not really a programming problem as stated. Also: "No."


Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not.

In the first, you have two `product` nodes, each with an `item` node underneath.

In the second, you have a single `product` node, with two `item` nodes underneath.

Answer (score 2):

They **are not** the same.

The first contains **2** products with **1** item each.

The second contains **1** product with **2** items.